# How did an attacker spoof (or add to) this myspace's login form?

Tags: web-application, xss, phishing

In the attack detailed [here](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2006/10/27/myspace_accounts_compromised_by_phishers.html), I see that a hacker has actually added a malicious `post` link. What I do not understand is how the attacker added it to the actual `myspace.com`domain.

Obviously this is an old issue but I'm still curious if there is an attack that can spoof the domain name itself.

Comment: If I remember correctly MySpace was inherently vulnerable to attacks.  Based on that link the domain itself wasn't spoofed, a legitimate web page was placed on its server.  The attacker most likely was able to hack the MySpace servers themselves.  Someone with more knowledge on the subject will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I wasnt sure if there was another form of uber-XSS out there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the article a user created a user named "login_home_index_html" then they used HTML and CSS to hide stuff on their profile page and make it look like it was the legitimate login page.  From what it looks like is MySpace didn't sanitize its user's custom HTML properly.

Comment: oh, I do not know how I missed that little tid bit of info. That makes much more sense!

Comment: MySpace used to allow full HTML to be used on all of their user info forms.  So under Interests you could just put full HTML with scripting.  This allowed users to customize their pages however they wanted, and malicious users to create custom login pages.

Comment: @RoraΖ that is not true. They allowed a very limited subset of HTML content. They used proprietary logic (inc a ton of regexes) to determine if you were trying to add things like some text in the color blue, versus javascript - which they obviously did not want. You could also not make forms, iframes.. etc. They actually did a fairly ok job at restricting the attack surface, but it was a problem that would never have a final solution as HTML is constantly changing. When Samy discovered a way to get XSS and created his worm, people realised it was a futile feature to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they spoofed the domain name.  I would say they either compromised the server or found some sort of HTML injection vulnerability that allowed them to just drop in the HTML that they wanted onto a "legitimate" myspace page that existed on their domain.